# Python flask datetimestamp formatting

Tags: python, arrays, json, flask

So i'm new to python and flask, i'm just wondering if there's a way to format 20210910103255 to 2021/09/10 10:32:55?? I tried using this code. It gets the job done but I want a better way to implement it. This was my code:

```
"date": as_json['array_id'].split("_")[3][:4] +'/' + as_json['array_id'].split("_")[3][4:6] + '/' + as_json['array_id'].split("_")[3][6:8]
            + ' ' + as_json['array_id'].split("_")[3][8:10] + ':' + as_json['array_id'].split("_")[3][10:12] + ':' + as_json['array_id'].split("_")[3][12:14]
```

Comment: `date = f"{array_id[:4}/{array_id[4:6]}/{array_id[6:8]} {array_id[8:10]}:{array_id[10:12]}:{array_id[12:]}"` considering `array_id = list("20210910103255")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, it gets the job done and does not spend unnecessary CPU cycles trying to parse and re-create the timestamp. For cleaner code, try using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

```
d = as_json['array_id'].split("_")[3]
"date": f"{d[:4]}/{d[4:6]}/{d[6:8]} {d[8:10]}:{d[10:12]}:{d[12:14]}"
```

This version is longer, but easier to comprehend:

```py
date = as_json['array_id'].split("_")[3]

year = date[:4]
month = date[4:6]
day = date[6:8]
hours = date[8:10]
minutes = date[10:12]
seconds = date[12:14]

"date": f"{year}/{month}/{day} {hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}"
```

Or, if you want to go the parsing route, use datetime:

```py
from datetime import datetime

date = as_json['array_id'].split("_")[3]
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
"date": datetime_object.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Thanks Jan! I used the f-string you mentioned and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I think datetime would be the best tool to help you here.

```
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime.now()
print(x)
```

More info can be found here https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datetime.asp

Comment: You should link to the official documentation for the datetime module, not w3schools: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dateutil` library for this:

```sh
$ pip install python-dateutil
```

In Python:

```py
>>> import dateutil
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('20210910103255').strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
'2021/09/10 10:32:55'
```